# Should I still truncate a postgresql database if I am truncating and refilling the tables instead of deleting/inserting/upserting?

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization, database-optimization

The production database at my company is running significantly slower than the test database (local ~5ms, test ~18ms, production ~1-2 sec). We've been trying to look into why and will be doing some `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on key queries on a secure shell psql instance in our cloud.

I've been trying to read up on database optimization and have come across postgresql's `VACUUM` and am wondering if running this might help. We don't update the production database often -- once each release, though the migrations involve dropping or truncating tables as necessary and then importing new data. I'm curious if VACUUM would be potentially helpful here? If it would be, would we be seeing similar slowdowns in a spiped instance of our test database?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for the slow query in production generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan (ideally with `track_io_timing` turned on). Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Have you turned off auto vacuum?

Comment: The description of the question is at odds with the title.  As a matter of fact, the title does not make sense.  There is no such thing as truncating a postgresql database, at least not as a separate notion from truncating each table therein.

Comment: What do you see if you `ping` the production database server?

Answer (score 0):

VACUUM could help if there are a lots of DELETE and UPDATE in the database.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36984/how-to-determine-if-a-postgres-database-needs-to-be-vaccumed